# WPF, access a proprety inside a usercintrol from a window.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I don't know if I'm very clear in my title but what i want to do is Bind a value of a usercontrol from a xaml file like window.xaml. For exemple:

```
<Views:Identify x:Name="identify" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

This is the usercontrol that i created in my windows.xaml.
My usercontrol looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="user"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="2">Connection</Button>
</Grid>
```

And I want to Bind the property "text" of the property "user" to a property that I have in the datacontext of Window.xaml. I want to do this binding:

```
        <TextBox Name="user" Text="{Binding client_.clientInfo_.name_, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

but from the windows.xaml. Is it possible ? I want to do it from the xaml file.
I think we can do something like that in the code behind of my usercontrol:

```
public TextBox user_
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            user = value;
        }
    }
```

But i would prefer to not touch to my code behind file. I don't know if it breaks the MVVM model or not. For me it does not but maybe I dont see it from the right angle. I would want to bind the property from my Windows.xaml file.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me. What do your mean by a "variable"? In C#, a variable can be defined only locally in a method. Do you mean a "property" perhaps? Why did you create an `UserControl`, do you actually need it? What do you mean by "Datacontext of Window.xaml"? The `DataContext` is a property of a `FrameworkElement` class, not of a XAML file. Please improve your question.

Comment: I edit. I just mean that my Window.xaml has a Datacontext, i set the windows Datacontext to my ViewModel. I'm not sure how it works, i'm just learning. But I just want to set a proprety inside my usercontrol like: myusercontrol.user.text = "toto" in my windows.xaml file, because my usercontrol will be use inside my windows.xaml file.